# play the same sound twice in a storyboard in wpf

Tags: c#, wpf, storyboard

I would like to play the same sound twice in a storyboard. 
Somehow this doesnt work and only plays the sound once (after 5 seconds):

```
    public ViewModel()
    {
        Storyboard sb = new Storyboard();
        MediaElementObject = new MediaElement();

        MediaTimeline mtl = new MediaTimeline(new Uri(@"./Resources/Ka-ching.Wav", UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute));

        mtl.BeginTime = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(0.3);
        Storyboard.SetTarget(mtl, MediaElementObject);
        sb.Children.Add(mtl);
        mtl.BeginTime = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5);
        Storyboard.SetTarget(mtl, MediaElementObject);
        sb.Children.Add(mtl);
        sb.Begin();
    }
```

The storyboard has two children, but the begintime of both children is set to 5 seconds. I have also tried  this (which would be more difficult to realize in the real situation, but it also doesn't work):

```
    public ViewModel()
    {
        Storyboard sb = new Storyboard();
        MediaElementObject = new MediaElement();

        MediaTimeline mtl = new MediaTimeline(new Uri(@"./Resources/Ka-ching.Wav", UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute));
        MediaTimeline mtl2 = new MediaTimeline(new Uri(@"./Resources/Ka-ching.Wav", UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute));

        mtl.BeginTime = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(0.3);
        Storyboard.SetTarget(mtl, MediaElementObject);
        sb.Children.Add(mtl);
        mtl2.BeginTime = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5);
        Storyboard.SetTarget(mtl2, MediaElementObject);
        sb.Children.Add(mtl2);
        sb.Begin();
    }
```

Now the children have two different start times (in the debugger) but it still only plays the sound once.

Comment: Have you tried to set `RepeatBehaviour` for the `Storyboard` item?